# Exit condition block for non-condition, or long block condition?

Tags: python, pep

I always wanted to ask this question. I would like to know what form I should use, and why. What is better:

```
if my_condition:
    # very long block of code with multiple indention levels
```

OR:

```
if not my_condition:
    exit

# Still here ?
# very long block of code with multiple indention levels
```

EDIT:

I'm not asking for personal opinion. Is there any PEP recommendation/ any criterion I'm not aware of ?

Comment: I am afraid this question will be closed as highly opinionated. Anyway, I prefer the first one, because that is more structured, reminds me of functional programming. The second one is more imperative, but in some scenarios you can avoid deep indentations.

Comment: Ok. Is it only personal, or is there any PEP recommendation I'm not aware of ?

Comment: @Rififi Best practice may very well be a matter of opinion.

Comment: Python has `break` statement that is used to break out of loop. If it was discouraged, then there' d be no break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> Flat is better than nested.

The second approach, `if not my_condition: exit`, avoids a level of nesting and is therefore superior according to this particular criterion.